# SwiftUI call function on tab view navigation

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, tabview

I want to execute functions when the user switches tabs in a `TabView`. Strangely, I can't seem to do this with `.simultaneousGesture`. How can I execute functions on the event of the user switching tabs in a tab view?

Sample Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                Text("View One")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("View One")
                }
                .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                    print("This isn't printing")
                })
            
                Text("View Two")
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("View Two")
                    }
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                        print("This isn't printing")
                    })
            
                 Text("View Three")
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("View Three")
                    }
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                        print("This isn't printing")
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Updated Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                Text("View One")
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("View One")
                }
            
                Text("View Two")
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("View Two")
                    }
            
                Text("View Three")
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("View Three")
                    }
            }
        }
        .onReceive(Just(selectedTab)) { thing in
            print("Tapped!!")
            print("\(thing)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64020773/12299030?

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I thought it would fix my problem, but actually it didn't. My publisher prints once when the view initializes, but not again upon changes to the selected tab. I'll post updated code

Comment: As usual, @Asperi answer works flawlessly. Look at his code again. In order for the selection to work, you have to tag the tabs, or the system doesn't know which is which. You left that out in your code. Either the `.onReceive` with the `Just` publisher, or `.onChange(of:)` works in this situation. Obviously, the `.onChange(of:)` is iOS 14+.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I forgot about the tabs

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.tag` modifier to each tab and use a custom `Binding` that does the work in the setter.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: Binding(
                get: { selectedTab },
                set: {
                    selectedTab = $0
                    print("switched to tab \(selectedTab)")
                }
            )) {
                Text("View One")
                    .tabItem { Text("1") }
                    .tag(1)
                Text("View Two")
                    .tabItem { Text("2") }
                    .tag(2)
                Text("View Three")
                    .tabItem { Text("3") }
                    .tag(3)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onAppear to run any function on tab selection. The following function clears the badge when the tab is selected.

```
ChatsView()
            .tabItem {
                selectedView == 1 ? SwiftUI.Image(systemName: "message.fill") : SwiftUI.Image(systemName: "message")
            }
            .tag(1)
            .badge(chatBadgeValue)
            .onAppear {
                chatBadgeValue=0
            }
```